# PDO INSERT prepared statement, no errors but data are not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to refactor my code to be PDO ready, but something is wrong and cannot understand what: The following code using PDO prepared INSERT query runs apparently Ok, I cannot get any error message (other than some Warning on "undefined indexes", but no data are inserted in the demographics table. I have also checked MySQL and I have the correct privileges to write or delete everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a print_r($_POST) that is working fine, but cannot get any value from the stmt->execute(); command (I have tried print_r($value = stmt->execute()); with no errors but no messages.  Here is the code:

```
// First --> Let us then include info regarding the connection to the database, PHP functions, and header section and page title

require('../../includes/config.inc.php');
require('../../includes/db_connection.php');
require('../../includes/functions.php');
require('../elements/layouts/header.php');

// Second --> Let's 'Check whether user has the rights to see current page or not

if(!isLoggedIn()) //"isLoggedIn" is a pre-specified function in functions.php file
    {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
    }

/*
Setup some variables/arrays: First we are creating a blank array called action and then setting an array value of result.
Result is going to hold a value of either success or error. Next we create another blank array called text.
This is going to hold any text we want to show the user during the signup.
*/
$action = array();
$action['result'] = null;
$text = array();

// Check if the form has been submitted:
if (isset($_POST['enroll'])) {


// On the other hand, if there are no errors, we can go ahead and enroll the patient:

    if($action['result'] != 'error'){



        // let's start a try/catch loop and submit the query via mysqli prepared statement

        try  {

            //let's define the variables involved, starting with the fields coming from the Demographics form

            $pid        = null; // this can be anything (MySQL will overwrite this value in any case)
            $addmod_ts  =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $address    =  $_POST['address'];
            $age    =   $_POST['age'];
            $censor_d   = $_POST['censor_d'];
            $city   =   $_POST['city'];
            $clinic =   $_POST['clinic'];
            $death  =   $_POST['death'];
            $dis_cat_main   =   $_POST['dis_cat_main'];
            $dis_cat_spec   =   $_POST['dis_cat_spec'];
            $disease_1  =   $_POST['disease_1'];
            $disease_2  =   $_POST['disease_2'];
            $disease_3  =   $_POST['disease_3'];
            $disease_4  =   $_POST['disease_4'];
            $dob    =   $_POST['dob'];
            $email_1    =   $_POST['email_1'];
            $email_2    =   $_POST['email_2'];
            $firstname  =   $_POST['firstname'];
            $fup_months =   $_POST['fup_months'];
            $fup_years  =   $_POST['fup_years'];
            $institution    = $_POST['institution'];
            $lastname   =   $_POST['lastname'];
            $locked =   $_POST['locked'];
            $notes  =   $_POST['notes'];
            $phone_1    =   $_POST['phone_1'];
            $phone_2    =   $_POST['phone_2'];
            $phone_3    =   $_POST['phone_3'];
            $physician  =   $_POST['physician'];
            $province   =   $_POST['province'];
            $pt_department  =   $_POST['pt_department'];
            $pt_location    =   $_POST['pt_location'];
            $recruit_ts =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $region =   $_POST['region'];
            $research   =   $_POST['research'];
            $saved  =   $_POST['saved'];
            $sex    =   $_POST['sex'];
            $specdis_1a =   $_POST['specdis_1a'];
            $specdis_1b =   $_POST['specdis_1b'];
            $ssn    =   $_POST['ssn'];
            $study  =   $_POST['study'];
            $zip    =   $_POST['zip'];
            $month  =   $_POST['month'];
            $day    =   $_POST['day'];
            $year   =   $_POST['year'];

            //Let us start basic validation: make sure everything required has been inserted

            if (empty($lastname)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert patient last name');
            }
            if (empty($firstname)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert patient first name ');
            }
            if (!is_numeric ($sex)) {
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert patient gender'); // SEX is a Number so must be treated accordingly (if empty does not work here)
            }
            if (empty($disease_1)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert at least the first medical issue'); // Disease_1 is a Number so must be treated accordingly (if empty does not work here)
            }
            if (empty($address)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert patient Address');
            }
            if (empty($city)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert city name');
            }
            if (empty ($phone_1)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert at least one valid phone number ');
            }
            if (empty($email_1)){
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert at least one valid e-mail address');
            }
            // then let us define and validate DOB and put the date in SQL format

            // Validate the month.
            if (is_numeric ($month)) {
                $dob = $month . '-';
            } else {
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert a valid Month for patient birth date');
            }
            // Validate the day.
            if (is_numeric ($day)) {
                $dob .= $day . '-';
            } else {
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert a valid Day for patient birth date');
            }
            // Validate the year.
            if (is_numeric ($year)) {
                $dob = $year . '-' . $month . '-' .  $day; // Set Birthdate in SQL format
            } else {
                $action['result'] = 'error'; array_push($text,'Please insert a valid Year for patient birth date');
            }


            // Finally, we can go ahead with the SQL INSERT query

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `demographics` (    PID,
                                                    ADDMOD_TS,
                                                    ADDRESS,
                                                    AGE,
                                                    CENSOR_D,
                                                    CITY,
                                                    CLINIC,
                                                    DEATH,
                                                    DIS_CAT_MAIN,
                                                    DIS_CAT_SPEC,
                                                    DISEASE_1,
                                                    DISEASE_2,
                                                    DISEASE_3,
                                                    DISEASE_4,
                                                    DOB,
                                                    EMAIL_1,
                                                    EMAIL_2,
                                                    FIRSTNAME,
                                                    FUP_MONTHS,
                                                    FUP_YEARS,
                                                    INSTITUTION,
                                                    LASTNAME,
                                                    LOCKED,
                                                    NOTES,
                                                    PHONE_1,
                                                    PHONE_2,
                                                    PHONE_3,
                                                    PHYSICIAN,
                                                    PROVINCE,
                                                    PT_DEPARTMENT,
                                                    PT_LOCATION,
                                                    RECRUIT_TS,
                                                    REGION,
                                                    RESEARCH,
                                                    SAVED,
                                                    SEX,
                                                    SPECDIS_1A,
                                                    SPECDIS_1B,
                                                    SSN,
                                                    STUDY,
                                                    ZIP
                                                              )
                                    VALUES (            :pid,
                                                        NOW(),
                                                        :address,
                                                        :age,
                                                        :censor_d,
                                                        :city,
                                                        :clinic,
                                                        :death,
                                                        :dis_cat_main,
                                                        :dis_cat_spec,
                                                        :$disease_1,
                                                        :disease_2,
                                                        :disease_3,
                                                        :disease_4,
                                                        :dob,
                                                        :email_1,
                                                        :email_2,
                                                        :firstname,
                                                        :fup_months,
                                                        :fup_years,
                                                        :institution,
                                                        :lastname,
                                                        :locked,
                                                        :notes,
                                                        :phone_1,
                                                        :phone_2,
                                                        :phone_3,
                                                        :physician,
                                                        :province,
                                                        :pt_department,
                                                        :pt_location,
                                                        NOW(),
                                                        :region,
                                                        :research,
                                                        :saved,
                                                        :sex,
                                                        :specdis_1a,
                                                        :specdis_1b,
                                                        :ssn,
                                                        :study,
                                                        :zip

                                                )';

            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindParam(':pid' , $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':addmod_ts' , $addmod_ts, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':address' , $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':age' , $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':censor_d' , $censor_d, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':city' , $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':clinic' , $clinic, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':death' , $death, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dis_cat_main' , $dis_cat_main, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dis_cat_spec' , $dis_cat_spec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':disease_1' , $disease_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':disease_2' , $disease_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':disease_3' , $disease_3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':disease_4' , $disease_4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dob' , $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email_1' , $email_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email_2' , $email_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':firstname' , $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':fup_months' , $fup_months, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':fup_years' , $fup_years, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':institution' , $institution, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lastname' , $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':locked' , $locked, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':notes' , $notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':phone_1' , $phone_1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':phone_2' , $phone_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':phone_3' , $phone_3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':physician' , $physician, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':province' , $province, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pt_department' , $pt_department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pt_location' , $pt_location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':recruit_ts' , $recruit_ts, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':region' , $region, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':research' , $research, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':saved' , $saved, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sex' , $sex, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':specdis_1a' , $specdis_1a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':specdis_1b' , $specdis_1b, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ssn' , $ssn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':study' , $study, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':zip' , $zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $stmt->execute();






            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            if (isset($errorInfo[2])) {
                print_r($error = $errorInfo[2]);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
                        }


        // Tell the user we have done successfully
        $action['result'] = 'success';
        array_push($text,'Patient is on Kardia now');


    }





    //A quick check of our action result value and we can continue on with the signup. If our result is error we will
    //skip over all the above code and output the errors to our user so they can make the necessary changes.
    // The last piece of this code we are putting the values of your text array into our action array.

    $action['text'] = $text;

}

?>

<?= show_errors($action); //This calls the function show_errors, to format validation appropriately ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your binds:

- `:$disease_1`: I think, it is `:disease_1`
- there is no placeholder named `addmod_ts` or `recruit_ts`

> I cannot get any error message

Are your `if` executed at least?

> other than some Warning on "undefined indexes"

Which are?

To use try/catch, do you have `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in first place?

Comment: thanks a lot for the debugging ! To answer your points in order: - yup :$disease_1 is definitely a typo, corrected (bit no success yet...sigh). - Yes I understand addmod_ts and recuit_ts (both timespamps) are MySQL functions (NOW()) but then how can I bindParam these values with the use of named placeholders ?. Yes, all the If statements are completed up to end with no issue . Yes, I have the correct ERRMODE attributes in the connction file, as you rightly suggested. Undefined Idexes on Age, DOB, Death, FUP_Months and FUP_Years (most of them are computed values)...THANKS, Appreciated !

Comment: You don't have to bind `addmod_ts` and `recuit_ts` (ie remove the bindParam lines) since these placeholders don't appear in the query. For the "undefined index" errors, check your form (edit your question if you need us to take a look at it) ;)

Comment: YES ! It worked :-) Just removing the wrong bindParam fixed the query and now data are added to the DB correctly :-) Thank you so very much, unvaluable help and support here, really appreciated ! Still I am a little bit worried that my errors handler policy could not help me to catch this...anyhow one mistake less I will not repeat (hopefully) in the future :)